# Rails has_many undefined method for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two objects: `Team` and `Player`.  As you could probably guess, a `Team` has many `Players` and a `Player` belongs to a team.

I understand that we can model this relationship with another model, `Team_Players` but I want to focus on the raw relationship here, as shown by many of the guides I'm seeing online.

When creating `Player`s, it's easy to assign them a `Team.id`, since they only have one, but the reverse -`has_many`- is more complicated.  The [Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) only shows the model file, so this is what mine looks like in reflection:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end
```

Now, I would expect to be able to do something like `Team.first.players` and be given an array or something, but instead I just get `undefined method player for #<Team:0x>` and in fact in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kI9KIh4ycAk), I do see a developer doing something just like that.  So what am I missing?  Do I *have* to make an intersection model here?  I would imagine not since `has_many` is inherent in Rails.

After creating the tables, I added the reference for `Team` to `Player` in this migration:

```
def change
  add_reference :players, :team, index: true
  add_foreign_key :players, :team
end
```

Again, since the has many relationship can't be modeled with a single column, I avoided that part in the migration.  Is that what's necessary for the desired functionality of `Team.first.players` returning an array or something?

Comment: `Team.players` is calling on the *class* `Team`. Only *instances* of `Team`s will have players, e.g., a team.

Comment: My mistake, I'll edit that. Even Team.first fails though

Comment: Your error says "undefined method player", not "players".

Comment: Produces the error I mentioned in the post. It seems to be unaware of the association I gave it.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you set up the belongs_to in your Players Class, ie `belongs_to: team`

Comment: It also says `#<Team:0x>`, do you actually have any teams?

Comment: also piggybacking off of @DaveNewton, did you seed your Team table with any records? What do you get when you call `Team.count` in your rails console?

Comment: No such thing! I did indeed. And that works, I can find a players team through player.team, but I suspect that is because of the table. @Dave Newton I've tried that as well. No luck

Comment: What specifically does it return when you type `Team.first.players`? You ran all migrations? Include your DB table defs in the question.

Comment: Before doing the association, I created some seeds.  I did the listed migration second, so now I can test my migrations with db:rollback and db:migrate without losing those seeds.

Comment: no such column: players.player.id:  So this sort of leads to the second part of my question, how can I make this association without the use of a second table?  Obviously it's looking for an Id, but I can't just give it one, I'll have to give it several - one for each player.

Comment: Your migration is wrong; the players table should have a team_id column, and that's it. Also, that's not what your question says; you should edit the question so it includes actual information.

Comment: so just the add_foreign_key?  I should nix add_reference?

Comment: That worked.  Team.first.players now gives me an array :)  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to get this to work:

`rails new teams` - followed by `bundle`

`rails g model Team name:string player_count:integer`

`rails g model Player player_name:string player_number:integer`

`rails g migration add_team_id_to_players`:

```
class AddTeamIdToPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :players, :team_id, :integer
  end
end
```

`rake db:migrate`

Here are my models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end
```

Then, in the console:

`Team.create(name: "Cats", player_count:1).save`

`Player.create(player_name: "Ryan", player_number:1, team_id:1).save`

Then voila:

`Team.first.players` returns:

```
Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams"  ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."team_id" = ?  [["team_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Player id: 2, player_name: "ryan", player_number: 1, created_at: "2015-12-18 19:32:39", updated_at: "2015-12-18 19:32:56", team_id: 1>]>
```

Comment: Yeah, you were missing the belongs_to :team and team_id in the database